# How do I use 2 loops in one program?

Tags: shell

Here is the code :

```
#!/bin/bash

while : 
do
now=$(date +" %m-%d-%Y Time: %T")
echo "Current Date : $now"
sleep 1

done

while :
do
echo "To cancel press [CTRL+C]"
sleep 28
done
```

The last loop is not outputting anything. How do I fix that?

Comment: Why would it? Its unreachable code

Comment: I agree with redFIVE

Comment: Seems like you'd be happier with: `echo 'To cancel, press [CTRL+C]'; while sleep 1; do printf 'Current Date : '; date +' %m-%d-%Y Time: %T' | tr \\n \\r; done`

Answer (score 2):

I think you actually want:

```
echo 'To cancel, press [CTRL+C]'
while sleep 1; do 
    printf 'Current Date : '
    date +' %m-%d-%Y Time: %T' | tr \\n \\r
done
```

Or, you could do something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0
while : $((i+=1)); do
  test $((i % 28)) = 1 &&
    echo "To cancel press [CTRL+C]"
  printf "Current Date : "
  date +" %m-%d-%Y Time: %T"
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed!